# Require that the input is in the datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an form input of type datalist, in this list is about 5000 options, because of the large amount of options a select form just is not practical as you are allowed to type and it suggests what you want with a datalist.

```
 <div class='form-row'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12 form-group required' style="margin-top: -2px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                        <h2><label class='control-label' style="font-size: 20px;">Product code</label></h2>
                        <input required id="ItemSelect" list=jobs style='font-size:21px;height: 40px;'
                               class='form-control'
                               name="Code">
                        <datalist id=jobs>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($this->Products as $a) {
                                $inputValue = "  " . htmlentities($a["Code"] . " | " . $a["Name"]) . " ";
                                echo '<option>' . $inputValue;
                            }
                            ?>
                        </datalist> 
                    </div>
```

This is what i have now, however the user can type and submit things that are not in the list and i can not allow this. How can i stop this from happening?

Comment: on submit get the closest match to the datafield value

Comment: or alert the user that the field is incorect

Comment: I cant get the closest match, it has to be one in the list, and these are product codes so  there can be multiple that are similar

Comment: And how would i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Alert the user if the field has a incorect value

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e) {
  $datalistval= $('#ItemSelect').val();
  if ($('option[value="'+$datalistval+'"]').length == 0) //if no option is found alert the user
   {
   alert('incorect datalist value');
   e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ev63ghwk/

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use jQuery UI's `autocomplete` this would work:

```
  <?php // tweak the below to use your data
        $arr = array( array('Name' => 'one'), array('Name' => 'two'), array('Name' => 'three') );
        $optsArr = array();
        foreach ($arr as $a) { 
          array_push( $optsArr , '"'.htmlentities( $a["Name"] ).'"' ); ;
        }
        $options = implode(",", $optsArr)
  ?>

 var availableTags = [<?php  echo $options ?>];
 $(function() {
     $( "#ItemSelect" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if(!ui.item){
                //http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change -
                // ui.item property is null if the input was not found in the list
                $("#ItemSelect").val("");
            }

        }
     });
 });
```

### Here's a [working Demo](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/autocomplete/forced-autocomplete.php)